# Can linux be booted from SeaBIOS?

Tags: linux, bios

https://doc.coreboot.org/tutorial/part1.html:

I followed the steps here and was able to run coreboot&seabios on qemu. After this step, I want to boot "linuximage.elf". I created a folder containing the linux image and gave it as a parameter to qemu. I saw this folder in boot options. But it couldn't boot. Can linux be booted from SeaBIOS?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly – you'll have to use an external Linux bootloader such as GRUB, Syslinux, or LILO. The Linux kernel itself *used to be,* but no longer is, directly bootable from a PC BIOS environment.

But you probably shouldn't use SeaBIOS at all, as its purpose is only to emulate a PC BIOS for booting an OS that *needs* a PC BIOS, but Linux doesn't need that – Linux can be booted directly as a Coreboot payload instead of SeaBIOS, it's even the [first section](https://www.coreboot.org/Payloads) in the payloads documentation.

(The kernel *is* directly bootable from an UEFI environment, though.)